# ethtool doesn't change the network speed in pre-up

Tags: networking, ethernet, systemd-networkd

I want to set the network speed so I created a script in `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/eth-tool`:

```
#!/bin/sh
ethtool eth0 -s speed 10 duplex full autoneg off
```

I set the execution permission, but on boot the network still work at 100 Mbps. I have a file inside `/etc/systemd/network/20-eth0.network` with this content:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DNS=192.168.0.1
Address=192.168.0.100/24
Gateway=192.168.0.1
```

Can I set here the network speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a systemd unit file for setting the speed automatically. The `.service` file would be something like

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=Setting Speed
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex full autoneg off
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`if-pre-up.d` should also work, bu you mentioned `~/etc` which I assume is a **typo**. It should be `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool`

Also, include the full pathname of your command `/sbin/ethtool`

Finally, test the `ethtool` from command line and make sure it switches the speed without any issue before trying it from the script because it might not be a problem with your script but with the driver or card or anything.

Comment: @Mark: What's your distro? I use Arch Linux and used the syntax found in this [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#systemd_service) page

Comment: It works, but it brings down the network a second time. I can live with that, but if there's a solution on `pre-up` I guess it would be more elegant.

Comment: it's a custom Yocto environment for an armv7l board.

Comment: Typo fixed. Added full path. Running the script works, but on boot it still connects at the default speed.

Comment: @Mark: If you run other scripts from that directory, does it work? Because the trend now is to use systemd rather than the **hook scripts**. [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/914493/ubuntu-18-04-doesnt-load-iptables-rules-after-reboot) .e.g also fails in new ubuntu

Comment: Well, I'm not sure... I leave with the `systemd` unit. Not so nice, but at least it works...